# Custom sized italic Font using Spannable

Tags: java, android, spannable

There is the following code:

```
String s = message + "\n" + date;
Spannable f = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(s);
f.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, message.length(), 0);
f.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), message.length() + 1, s.length(), 0);

textView.setText(f);
```

This code works fine for setting up diffent colors for textView. But I need another feature - I'd like that "date" has got smaller size of font and italic typeface. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 7):

Check this

[Different font size of strings in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview/16335416#16335416)

Try the below

```
String title="My Custom Text!";  
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_id);
SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(title);
ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, ss1.length(), 0);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, ss1.length, 0); 
tv.setText(ss1);
```

For more styling

http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/android_textview_rich_text_spannablestring

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is **absolutely possible**. You can simply add another **Span**:

```
Spannable.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), from, to, 0);
Spannable.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(float size), from, to, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

In this case, its a `StyleSpan` to *Italic* and a `RelativeSizeSpan`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Html.fromHtml("your html string"), to do any style you want in HTML and then show it in the textview as shown below:

```
 Spanned htmlText = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.yourStringResource));
 yourTextView.setText(htmlText, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

And the XML string.xml, must have the string declared as shown below:

```
 <string name="yourStringResource"><![CDATA[BLA BLA BLA BLA <br/> BLABA <font color="blue" size="6">COLORED HTML</font>]]></string>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML tags, like this:

```
String s = "<html>" + message + "<br /><i><small>" + date + "</i></small></html>";
```