# How to convert part of a string to italics?

Tags: android

I want to make `animal.getScientificName` as Italics(code below). I'm using a List View and setting the text in the listview. I wan't only part of the Text view to be in Italics, Is there anyway I can accomplish this. 
I have attached part of the code below,
Thanks for your help.

```
String[] listNames;

listNames[ i ] = animal.getName().toUpperCase().replaceAll( "_" , " " ) + " \n\n" + "+animal.getScientificName()+"; 


array_sort = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( listNames) ); 
tv.setText( array_sort.get( position ) );
```

Comment: use android spannable
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `Html.fromHtml`:

```
listNames[ i ] = animal.getName().toUpperCase().replaceAll( "_" , " " ) + " \n\n" + "<em>+animal.getScientificName()+</em>"; 


array_sort = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList( listNames) ); 
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(array_sort.get( position ) ));
```

for more info, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Comment: Very simple and Perfect. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using spans on your text (to expand here on the correct answer in comment by Georgian Benatos).

Here is a related question, and the answers show you exactly how to do this:

- [Custom sized italic Font using Spannable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18621691/custom-sized-italic-font-using-spannable)

Specifically some sample code in the [answer provided by Raghunandan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622052/383414)

```
String title="My Custom Text!";  
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.some_id);
SpannableString ss1=  new SpannableString(title);
ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.ITALIC), 0, ss1.length(), 0);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, ss1.length, 0); 
tv.setText(ss1);
```

---

Spans are a very useful feature - they can be used for various common text styles:

- italics
- bold
- underline
- bullets

To have a look at the wide range of spans available, take a look at the Android developers page for the `android.text.style` package:

- [android.text.style | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks will have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using two TextViews, because it is impossible to have two different text-styles in one TextView.

Just place them both under each other, and assign the correct String value to the TextView.

```
tv1.setText(animal.getName().toUpperCase().replaceAll( "_" , " " );
tv2.setText(animal.getScientificName();
```

And for example, you can use this layout in your ListView item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. [Use spans on your text to accomplish this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25852468/383414) - a little known feature, but very powerful.

Comment: I had a look but , That seems a bit complex for my task :)