# How to make editetext text as Italic,Underline and Highlighted in Android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application,i have a requirement that,whenever user typing in edit text the text should become italic,underlined and highlighted.Please can help me.

Thanking In Advance.

Comment: use spannable string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview/16335416#16335416 and you can make it italic also

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText txt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt);

txt.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF, Typeface.BOLD); //you can change fonts as you like
```