# How to change text Size and color of single word in Text View

Tags: android, textview

I am designing an Application where i can change size and color of single word. I attached image as below.This is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/listview_with_ad"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#00FFFF"
android:textSize="24"
android:text="Download these two Application and get the Environmental Lighting feature for FREE" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I want to display "Free" word with big text size and different color. Any Suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Set text using html and css https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094315/single-textview-with-two-different-colored-text/6094346#6094346

Comment: I it possible to change in xml file rather than code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `SpannableString`, it's a powerful tool that you can use to set multiple styles in `TextView`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview).