# Multiple TextViews in a LinearLayout, Last TextView should start with a new line when text goes beyond screen width

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I have three TextViews in a LinearLayout. I want the last TextView to appear in a new line (from the left most side) when Text goes out of bound of the screen width.

Below is the Xml Code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/topContainer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/general_padding"
android:gravity="center_vertical">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/objectNameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Will Smith "
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/orange_app_color" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/postDetailTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="is now following "
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subjectNameTv"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Kia Kool hain Hum"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/orange_app_color" />

</LinearLayout> </RelativeLayout>
```

[xml layout screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJcXH.png)

Thanks

Comment: i don't see the purpose of having nested `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout` . To display those text you don't need 3 textviews. you can have a single textview that does the job

Comment: you can only do this programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this from xml but you could do this programatically using only one TextView. I hope that this post will help you: [Different font size of strings in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview)

Comment: Thanks David, I have achieved the required result through Spannable String.