# Android two Textview with "wrapcontent" in single line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview

I am unable to get a seemingly easy layout configuration right !!

I have two textview in a Relative (tried Linear with orientation horizontal) both "wrapcontent" - I want them one beside other. Something like:

> 1. First Text || Second Text [*this is of smaller text size*]
>
>    (For Small Title works good)
>
> [image]

When the first text is long - longer than what can be displayed in one line then the first text goes to second line and the second Textview disappears (goes to deep right). Something like below:

> 2.For long Title - observe the count disappears to right
>
> [image]

```
          <RelativeLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/feedHeader"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView1"
                    style="@style/BoldTitle"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                    android:text="Title Loooooooggggggg Title Looong"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pageCounts"
                    style="@style/WayBoardCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:minWidth="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/textView1"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textView1"
                    android:checked="false"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:text="3/5"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

> I want small text (count) to be beside "Looong" and not disappear on the right
>
> 1. Tried "Min Size for the second textview"
> 2. Linear Layout with Horizontal Orientation

**EDIT:** 
Some Solutions/Answers given in this thread that still doesn't address my problem (For the benefit of someone else I have my output below):

> Alexander :
>   [image]

Comment: If you don't find any solution for this, then you can use a single textview for showing both the title as well as count and change the size of later part to be smaller than the starting part using SpannableStrings.

Comment: @ankitaggarwal agree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your problem. So you can use [spannable](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/Spannable.html). Useful link about [metrics](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/text/style/MetricAffectingSpan.html).
Hope it helps [tutorial](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/introduction-to-spans/)

Simple cod:

```
private void updateText(TextView textView, String bigText, String smallText) {
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(bigText + smallText);
    spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.4f), 0, bigText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    spannableString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.0f), bigText.length(), spannableString.length(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    textView.setText(spannableString);
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't help - coz For "Small Title" - giving weight makes the "small text" go to the extreme right

Comment: @takrishna do you use **wrap_content** for **width** in LinearLayout?

Comment: yes.. the "small text" doesn't start right after "G" of "Looong" (see the image I have uploaded) - I am thinking may be this is Android platform's limitation

Comment: can you share your full layout? I see that you attached not full source code.

Comment: I have put what I got as output - Hope I am clear now - I mean as an edit to the question itself - some screen grabs

Comment: Yes Alex, I found that Friday - forgot to update this thread !!

Answer (score 2):

You can try with

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="1" >
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Title Loooooooggggggg Title Looong"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pageCounts"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="3/5"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

### Note

**You cant showing in single line if Text is too Large** . On that time you can use **[android:ellipsize](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:ellipsize)**

```
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Comment: I don't want to ellipsize - Want the first text to be fully shown after which the second text (which is count) to be displayed - the count is of "smaller text size" hence using two textviews - else I could have simply appended my count the the only textview

Comment: @takrishna problem for large text . you can follow #ankitaggarwal's tips

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:text="VeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongText"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

  <TextView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:gravity="start|bottom"
      android:layout_height="5dp"
      android:textSize="5sp"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
      android:text="SmallText"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: weight is same and "1" doesn't work Mahesh ! - same result

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the same with `RelativeLayout`, following is a dummy code

```
         <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/feedHeader"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/pageCounts"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                 android:checked="false"
                 android:text="3/5"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/textView1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                 android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                 android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView2"
                 android:paddingBottom="0dp"
                 android:text="Title Loooooooggggggg Title Looong Loong"
                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

         </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I don't want to alignparentRight dude - I want it to align rightof "First Text" - but when the first text is long I want the second text to be displayed after the first text is done displaying

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was looking for "Span-able String" !!

> Details here:
>   [Different font size of strings in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview)