# Android: different formatting styles applied to one textview

Tags: android, css

I have one text view in my XML and in that text view i have a large number of text which i would like to apply different formatting styles to different text in the text view. Like center alignment,different fonts,different font size and underline.How do I achieve this?
My sample code is below:

```
String [] item = {"Chicken BBQ bacon \n \n BBQ Chicken,Bacon,Sweet Corn,Onion \n \n <b>Regular</b> sh 500 \n \n Medium sh 700 \n \n Large sh 900 \n \n","Chicken and Mushroom \n \n chicken,mushroom \n \n Regular  Medium  Large \n \n sh500 sh700 sh900"}

description.setText(Html.fromHtml(item[x]));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple styles inside a TextView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529068/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-styles-inside-a-textview)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SpannableString`
Take a look for an example here: 
[Different font size of strings in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview)

Or using HTML tags, take a look:
http://daniel-codes.blogspot.co.il/2011/04/html-in-textviews.html

Comment: the problem with spannable string is that i will have to find position of characters in a word and i have like 100 words inside my textview. Is there a simpler way to do it.The string i posted above is just a sample not the whole text.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found an interesting library regarding Textview

[advanced android Textview](https://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/)

You can add various Styles,arbitary fractions,Spannable Strings,Alignment Span,Rainbow Span,Unicode with System fonts,Custom Fonts etc.

Hope it helps to enhance your creativity more!!Happy Coding!!

Comment: The link you sent above is not working. Could you please give me another.

Comment: well i clicked on above link in my case its working..Any way here is link to official github library https://github.com/chiuki/advanced-textview  an above link i have provided is of Companion app for demostrating how to use it....If it helps u please acknowledge my answer by accepting or by upvoting it..Happy coding buddy.

Comment: I have checked out the link and it works. I have found very useful information which i highly appreciate but none seems to answer my question.Thanks anyway.