# TextView title?

Tags: android

I wanna make a textView with this design but I really don't know how to do it?

[image]

Comment: Please show what you have tried to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use SpannableString text.

You will customize your text inside one TextView.

Samples here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-font-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview/16335416)

Comment: That's quit nice but I also need to have different background between both ??