# Android TextView making the font different size per line

Tags: android, textview, material-design

I want to use a TextView

The first line, I want the font to be 24dp
the second line, I want the font to be 16dp

Could this be done with 1 TextView or will I need to create 2 of them?

Comment: `will I need to create 2 of them` - easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done in 1 TextView with SpannableString

From https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan

You can use:

```
SpannableString string = new SpannableString("Text with relative size span");
string.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(1.5f), 10, 24, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Where 1.5f would be an increase of 50%, 10 the starting index and 24 the end index

```
public void setSpan (Object what, 
                int start, 
                int end, 
                int flags)
```

Another example here [Different font size of strings in the same TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-font-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview) too

Comment: Thanks. I was going to use Kotlin but now that I know what I am looking for. It shouldn't be that much harder