# TextView showing price with digits after decimal point with smaller text size than the rest

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I need to show the price in the Android app. Design is such that text size of two digits after the decimal point is smaller than the rest of the text. I know I can achieve this with multiple `TextView` views but I'm wondering if anyone did it without the use of multiple views and how to do it.

TL;DR Price should be formatted like this: **5,oo USD** (**oo** in this example represents two zeros as in zero cents with text size smaller than the number **5** which represents the number of dollars)

Comment: have you tried using `Html.fromHtml(yourString) `?

Comment: Try `SpannableString`, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16335178/different-font-size-of-strings-in-the-same-textview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AbsoluteSizeSpan for your `TextView`

```
SpannableStringBuilder yourText = new SpannableStringBuilder("5.00 USD");
span.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(fontsize, true), start, end,Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
yourTextView.setText(span)
```

You can find more information from  [developer webpage](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/AbsoluteSizeSpan)

Answer (score 0):

You can
Check the font face that it zeros are smaller that the rest of the digit and apply it.